# i18n in Angular: Avoid duplications in translation file and component

Tags: angular, internationalization

While successfully internationalize my application, I unfortunately noticed that the translated string is not only stored in the translation file (`messages.json`), but still has to be existing in the component itself. That behaviour seems a bit strange since the strings are a duplications of eachother, stored out of sync.

I would like to change the strings only in the default translation file. At the moment, I have to change it in the component as well.

**Here is an example:**

`table.component.html`

```
<div>
  <p i18n="@@table-no-entries">No entries</p>
</div>
```

If I leave the text between the `<p>` tag empty, an empty string is shown (in the default language;  for "de" the right string is shown). However, I would expect, since the same string is already stored in the translation file, that `@@table-no-entries` works like a variable, which than fills the content between the brackets with the string `No entries`, defined in the translation file.

**The translation files:**

`messages.json` (default translation file)

```
{
  "locale": "en",
  "translations": {
    "table-no-entries": "No entries",
}
```

`messages.de.json` (de translation file)

```
{
  "locale": "de",
  "translations": {
    "table-no-entries": "Keine Einträge",
}
```

**Configuration in Angular.json**

`angular.json`

```
...
"projects": {
   ...
   "i18n": {
     "sourceLocale": "en",
     "locales": {
       "de": "src/locale/messages.de.json"
   }
   ...
}
...

"architect": {
    "build": {
      ...
      "configurations": {
        "de": {
          "localize": ["de"],
          "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
        },
        ...
      },
      ...
   },
   ...
}
...
```

Oh and: The variables are extracted by using `ng extract-i18n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one who is also struggeling with similar problems:

I am now using [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) which serves my purpose thanks to its integrated translation service and pipes.